# Azure TFS: Setting a Variable Value From File

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, yaml

I am writing an Azure Pipeline with YAML file, and would like to have the name of the pipeline to contain the current version.
My question is basically how can I set a variable by reading from a file or from stdout. Something like:

```
name: $(GradleVersion)
variables:
  GradleVersion: <Get this value from a file or stdout>
```

More specifically:
The artifact is a Java artifact built with Gradle. Part of the task is to version the artifact: `<major>.<minor>.<build>`.
This string is available in a file prior to running the pipeline.

Is there a way to add this value into a variable inside the pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `variables` block you can't set the value from reading a file.

What you can do for achieve your goal is to add a simple PowerShell task that read the version from the file and set it as build name with [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash). something like:

```
$file = Get-Content path/to/file
$version = extract the version from the file, with regex, etc.
# Set the build name with the version
Write-Host ##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$version
```